# what's the absolute shortest d3 area example?

Tags: d3.js

I'm really struggling to understand d3's `area` and `stack` layout stuff. I tried making what I thought was the smallest example but nothing appears and in fact it prints errors in the console. What am I not getting? Here's the code.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300)

var testData = [
  [ 0, 10],
  [10, 20],
  [20, 30],
  [30, 20],
];

svg.selectAll("path.area")
    .data(testData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", "#ff0000")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dimension of the data is not correct. Each area path needs a 2D array, like this:

```
d3.svg.area()([[ 0, 10], [10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 20]])
```

results in:

```
"M0,10L10,20L20,30L30,20L30,0L20,0L10,0L0,0Z"
```

That means that you need to bind a 3D array to the selection. Each element (i.e. path) in the selection will then receive a 2D array.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300)

var testData = [
  [ 0, 10],
  [10, 20],
  [20, 30],
  [30, 20],
];

svg.selectAll("path.area")
    .data([testData])      // dimension of data should be 3D
  .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", "#ff0000")
    .attr("class", "area") // not the cause of your problem
    .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
```

Sometimes it's easier to picture what is going on by imagining that you would like to create multiple areas. Then it would look like:

```
var testData1 = [
  [ 0, 10],
  [10, 20],
  [20, 30],
  [30, 20],
];

var testData2 = [
  [100, 110],
  [110, 120],
  [120, 130],
  [130, 120],
];

svg.selectAll("path.area")
    .data([testData1, testData2])
  .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", "#ff0000")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm slowly getting the hang of D3.

Comment: For the record, here is a jsFiddle for the 1st example http://jsfiddle.net/jSNHa/